# How can I extract the API details for the current day only?

Tags: date, livecode

I have the following bit of code, which gives me all the information about IBM in dictionary format, but it includes the same information for many different dates far behind the current date. How would I extract the information for the CURRENT date only?

```
on mouseUp
   put url("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=YPMBUVQ8AJXX1HQP") into field "myData"
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to parse each small block of text by date. The "itemDelimiter" can be set to any string, and looking at the contents of the url call, I would use the string "{,".

Now you can, for example:

```
 on mouseUp
   put url("https://www.alphavantage.co/query function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=YPMBUVQ8AJXX1HQP") into field "myData"

   set the itemDel to "},"
   answer item 6 of fld "myData"
end mouseUp
```

You can collect each item as required and process away.

Answer (score 0):

You get JSON from the service so I do think that the best solution is to convert from JSON to an array. You can do that with ImportJSON or JSON like:

```
put url("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=YPMBUVQ8AJXX1HQP") into tData
put JSONToArray(tData) into tArr   
# Get current date as ISO-date!
put the date into tDate
convert tDate to dateItems
put item 1 to 3 of tDate into tDate
replace "," with "-" in tDate
# Now get the current item in the array
put tArr["Time Series (Daily)"][tDate] into tToday
# To view in a normal field you can use combine 
combine tToday with return and tab
put tToday into field "myData"
```

In the long run I really think you will have a much easier run if you convert JSON to something more manageable before proceeding.